# Method with generic return type in lambda causes compile error

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a method performing a rest call and returning an object of the type passed to the method:

```
    private <T> T getForObject(String url, Class<T> returnClass) throws IOException {...}
```

When using this method in a lambda expression (below), I get a compile error.

```
    List<Object> parentIds = upC.getIds().stream()
        .map(cId -> getForObject("/my/url/" + id, WrapperClass.class))
        .map(wrapper -> wrapper.getParentId())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The error:

```
Wrong 2nd argument type: found 'java.lang.Class<package.WrapperClass>',
required 'java.lang.Class<T>'.
```

It's strange, since I have used this method successfully outside of the lambda:

```
getForObject("/other/url/" + objectId, OtherClass.class);
```

Is it not possible to use this type of method inside a lambda?

Comment: huh - it should not compile because your method throws a checked exception, not because of the generic type. If you remove the checked exception from your method signature it should compile fine.

Comment: You're right, I've removed the exception and it cleared the error. This cost me a bit of time though. Thanks a lot.